# Having a Hungarian PR, but a non-European passport. Can I use interrail?

Tags: eurail, interrail

I am actually quite confused, I have a Hungarian permanent residence but I live outside europe and carry a non-European citizenship.
I can enter any european country without needing a visa though. Does that mean I am eligible to get an interrail or is the eurail my only choice?

Answer (score 2):

Interrail passes are available to European citizens *and* residents. As a resident of Hungary, you are therefore entitled to travel with an Interrail pass.

Be aware though, that your Hungarian residence permit alone, does not allow you to enter all other European countries without a visa if you with your citizenship otherwise would have needed one.

Comment: Are you sure that the OP won't be allowed to travel to other countries without a visa? https://helpers.hu/visa-free-travel-countries-hungary/ "The Hungarian resident permit is as good as a golden visa to Europe, since a third country national in possession of a valid resident permit is eligible for entering and staying in the territory of the Schengen Member States without possessing a visa for a period not exceeding 90 days within 180 days."

Comment: @greatone There are about 20 countries in Europe, which are *not* part of the Schengen area and to which a Hungarian residence permit does not necessarily grant access.